# laravel recursion display referred users by level/depth

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I'm working with affiliate and doing fine with registration and saving who referred to a user,
now I'm struggling in showing those users with referrals by Level.

Level is not save in the database, I'm thinking of it as incrementing in the logic area?

users table structure

```
id |  name  | sponsor_id |
 1 |  John  |    NULL    |
 2 |  Jane  |      1     |
 3 |  Jess  |      1     |
 4 |  Joe   |      2     |
```

so the output I want should be like this:

I am `John`, level 1 are who's sponsor_id is mine, and level 2 are who's sponsor_id is id's of whom I invited.

```
ID |  Name  |  Level  |
2  |  Jane  |    1    | 
3  |  Jess  |    1    |
4  |  Joe   |    2    |
```

where `Jane & Jess`'s sponsor_id is mine, and `Joe`'s sponsor_id is `Jess`

User has sponsor

```
public function sponsor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'sponsor_id');
}
```

User has referrals

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'sponsor_id');
}
```

Comment: I think recursion is not required here, as you're expecting the `sponser_id` which is directly mapped with the used. You can use a `self-join` like `employee-manager` and get that data.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If MySQL 8 (very advised with hierarchical data like yours), you can do this with a recursive CTE :

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE_users_levels(id, name, level) AS 
    ( 
          SELECT id, name, 0 as level
          FROM users 
          WHERE sponsor_id IS NULL 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT u.id, u.name, cte.level+1 
          FROM CTE_users_levels cte 
          JOIN users u ON cte.id=u.sponsor_id
    ) 

-- To output all users' levels:
SELECT * FROM CTE_users_levels ORDER BY level;
```

Now you have virtual table containing the `level` column for all your users and you can query it

```
| id  | name | level |
| --- | ---- | ----- |
| 1   | John | 0     |
| 2   | Jane | 1     |
| 3   | Jess | 1     |
| 4   | Joe  | 2     |
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x75WLaKMvwNeogJNP9hhDm/0)

---

GOing further...

Make a view out of your CTE

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_User_Levels AS
(
WITH RECURSIVE CTE_users_levels(id, name, level) AS 
    ( 
          SELECT id, name, 0 as level
          FROM users 
          WHERE sponsor_id IS NULL 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT u.id, u.name, cte.level+1 
          FROM CTE_users_levels cte 
          JOIN users u ON cte.id=u.sponsor_id
    ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE_users_levels ORDER BY level   
  
 )
```

Now it's easy to get all your users levels (no need to have the CTE statement) :

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_User_Levels
```

Then, if you have a lot of users, it's a bit ovekilling to recompute the whole tree all the time (which the VIEW does)

Then you can fix the level of your users in a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD level INT;
```

And populate that column for all users with the help of your view:

```
UPDATE users u, VIEW_User_Levels v
SET  u.level=v.level
WHERE u.id=v.id;
```

Which gives

```
SELECT * FROM users

id  name    sponsor_id  level
1   John    null        0
2   Jane    1           1
3   Jess    1           1
4   Joe     2           2
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x75WLaKMvwNeogJNP9hhDm/0)

If you have a lot of users, and your aim is to query the level column a lot, INDEX IT.

Note that you can also update the level value of only one user (for instance if its sponsor_id changes, or if the user is new)

```
UPDATE users u, VIEW_User_Levels v
SET  u.level=v.level
WHERE u.id=v.id AND u.name='Jane';
```

Comment: how about if I don't want to include myself? it will start showing on my level 1

Comment: as simple as `SELECT * FROM CTE_users_levels WHERE level>0;`

Comment: and if less that level 10, the query would be `WHERE level > 0 AND level < 11` ?

Comment: thank you Thomas, I'm new to CTE recursive, is it a fast query?

Comment: This all depends of your number of users. Recomputing the whole tree if you have millions of them, might be a bit heavy, with thousands there's no issue. If you really have a lot of users, I would recommend to create a level column somewhere (in the user table is fine), and to (re)compute with a batch, or when the user register, or when the hierarchy tree changes. You can do an UPDATE statement from the CTE.

Comment: what do you mean with the level column? i will save the level? but how. your help is highly appreciated for a newbie like me thanks a lot Thomas

Comment: I have another question, how can I pass the current user id? I tried `WHERE sponsor_id = 2` and I'm getting null

Comment: already check my adapted answer. Got to go now, I might come back later on ;)